# Проверить существование элемента объекта и его заполненность

Tags: javascript

Есть объект

```
let ob = {
    0: [1,2,3],
    7: []
};
```

Пытаюсь написать функцию, которая бы проверяла существование запрашиваемого ключа в этом объекте, а также убеждалась, что там не пусто массив (не массива быть там не может). Но ничего не выходит -  `console.log(ob[2]);` возвращает *undefined*, но вместе с тем условия не срабатывает. Что не так?

```
search_filter_kits(ob) {
    console.log(ob[2]);
    if (ob[2] != 'undefined') {
        let my_array= ob[2];
        if (my_array.length > 0) {
            return my_array;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в данном случае `ob[2] != 'undefined'` сравнение идет со **строкой**.

Надо же сравнивать со **значением** [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined): `ob[2] != undefined`

Либо проверять тип `ob[2]` с помощью [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), который действительно строка:

```
typeof ob[2] != 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверка на существование ключа/свойства в объекте:

```js
let ob = {
  0: [1, 2, 3],
  7: []
};
if (7 in ob) {
  console.log("has 7");
}
if (!(3 in ob)) {
  console.log("does not have 3");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let ob = {
    0: [1,2,3],
    7: []
};

function search_filter_kits(obj, key) {
    if (obj[key] !== undefined) {
        let my_array = obj[key];
        if (my_array.length > 0) {
            return my_array;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

console.log("key = 2", search_filter_kits(ob, 2));
console.log("key = 0", search_filter_kits(ob, 0));
```